# Using backslash in display dialog in AppleScript

Tags: bash, shell, applescript, ip-address, backslash

I am using AppleScript to output the IPAddress of my machine when I am connected to a WiFi network.
In Bash Script, I used this command:

`ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d\  -f2`

But when I use the same command in AppleScript, it gives me an error.
Here is the AppleScript:

```
tell application "Terminal"
activate
set IPAddr to do shell script "ifconfig | grep \"inet\" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d\ -f2"
display dialog IPAddr
end tell
```

In the Result, it would display:

```
 error "Terminal got an error: User canceled." number -128
```

I am assuming the problem is the backslash that I am using in the terminal command.
How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot!
Cheers

Comment: Use: `set IPAddr to do shell script "ifconfig | awk '/broadcast/{print $2}'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another backslash to escape the first one.
Consider also the two space characters between `d\\` and `-f2` and the space character after `inet`.

The `Terminal` tell block is not needed

```
set IPAddr to do shell script "ifconfig | grep \"inet \" | grep -v 127.0.0.1  | cut -d\\  -f2"
display dialog IPAddr
```